# Singularities in gauge-fixing conditions and topological defects

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, string, gauge

I am studying the 't Hooft's paper "Topology-of-the-gauge-condition-and-new-confinement" https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(81)90442-9 and there are several points which I would like to understand.

In the section 2 of the paper he considers the Abelian Higgs model, and at first takes chooses the unitary gauge condition :
$$
\mathrm{Re} \ \phi  = \rho > 0 \qquad \mathrm{Im } \ \phi = 0. 
$$
At a points, where $\phi = 0$ it is said that there develops a singularity, and because there are two indepent conditions - these define a 2D object in spacetime (string in space). How can one understand that there *has to be some singularity*? As far as I understand, the problem is, that for points, where $\phi$ vanishes phase is not defined, but how does it make this points in spacetime special? Moreover, the two conditions on $\phi(x)$ are not always independent, and for some choice of $\phi(x)$ do not specify any points. Or the case is that we look at fluctuating quantum fields in the functional integral, so for *generic field configuration*, except some rare cases, so the statement holds?

Then in the section 3, 't Hooft proceeds to the non-Abelian case. He introduces some tensor $X$, transforming in the adjoint represantation of the gauge group and lists some possible candidates. If it is brought to a diagonal form:
$$
X = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1 & & 0 \\
& \ddots & \\
0 & & \lambda_N
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then the singularities are, where the two or more eigenvalues coincide. Like in the Abelian case, how can one understand, that there is something special for this points, which leads to the stringy behaviour?

I would appreciate any help or comments.